# A shell script for joining two files

Tags: text-processing, awk, join

I want to write a `shell script` that get two files `A` and `B`, and get a result like this:

File `A`:

```
user_a tel_a addr_a
user_b tel_b addr_b
```

File `B`:

```
process_1 user_a
process_2 user_a
process_3 user_b
```

And the result:

```
user_a process_1 tel_a addr_a
user_a process_2 tel_a addr_a
user_b process_3 tel_b addr_b
```

How can i do this? `awk` or something else?

Comment: I think it can be done using `cut` and `paste` only, but I do not get the synthax right.

Comment: My files have many records and fields, i can't cut and paste!! This is just a sample.

Comment: @NavidFarhadi not cut&paste: there are two actual command `cut` and `paste` look at their manual page.

Comment: I can load both files in memory completely and i can also use awk.

Comment: I also can use perl or others, if they were executable in linux command line.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`join` ...

```
join -1 2 -2 1 FileB FileA
```

Output

```
user_a process_1 tel_a addr_a
user_a process_2 tel_a addr_a
user_b process_3 tel_b addr_b
```

The input files need to be sorted by the key field ... Your example files are already sorted, so there was no need, but otherwise you could incorporate the sort as follows.

```
join -1 2 -2 1 <(sort -k2 FileB) <(sort FileA)
```

Comment: What means the number parameters?

Comment: @Navid: You can always get the best and most accurate description of a command's paramaters by refering to the *manual*, by typing `man join` into the terminal's command-line...  `-1 2   -2 1`  means: join on the **'1st-file 2nd-field'** and the  **'2nd-file 1st-field'**

Answer (score 3):

Since `join` and `paste` aren't available everywhere (they're not on my BusyBox-based system, for example), here is how to do it with awk, as requested:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    while( (getline < "fileA") > 0) A[$1]=$2 OFS $3 # read fileA into the array A
    close("fileA")
  } {
    print $2, $1, A[$2]
  }' fileB
```

Comment: BTW you missed the seperator `A[$1]=$2 OFS $3` ... Here is another variant which avoids the manual loop in BEGIN, but it's pretty much the same (to *awk*), although it does introduce an otherwise unnecessary condition test for the second file: `awk 'NR==FNR {A[$1]=$2 OFS $3;next} {print $2, $1, A[$2]}' fileA fileB` ...(+1)