# How can I match a field in two different files and append together in output file?

Tags: awk, join

I need to match two unequal files using $1 of file 1 and $2 of file 2 and print $1 of file 2 on file 1.

**Input file 1**

```
101 2
101 5
101 7
103 2
103 3
103 4
105 3
105 2
```

**Input file 2**

```
24 101
23 103
26 105
```

**Desired output**

```
101 2 24
101 5 24
101 7 24
103 2 23
103 3 23
103 4 23
105 3 26
105 2 26
```

I have tried the following code but it gave me incorrect output.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$2]=$0;next};{print a[$2]}' file2 file1
```

Comment: Almost duplicate of [joining two files](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32746)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A classic job for `join`:

```
join -1 1 -2 2 file1 file2
```

- `-1 1` specifies the field in the first file.
- `-2 2` specifies the field in the second file.

Comment: Notice, though, that this requires that the field you join on is sorted in both files (they happen to be in this instance).

Answer (score 0):

Starting from your code, I also post an `awk` solution because you were almost there:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { a[$2]=$1; next; } { print $0,a[$1] } ' file2 file1
```

Output:

```
101 2 24
101 5 24
101 7 24
103 2 23
103 3 23
103 4 23
105 3 26
105 2 26
```